# What does an NG Ground Fault error status indicate?

Tags: honda, diagnostics, hybrid, electric-vehicle

This is for a Honda Clarity 2018 PHEV non-touring.  Error shows up in the diagnostics screens.

EDIT: adding photos...

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Furthermore, it should be noted that while the error appears to be persistent (I can't recall if it's always been there or not, but ever since I first noticed it, it has always remained the same), I can't seem to find any actual problem that could be associated with it (at least not that I've been able to notice).  There certainly hasn't been any issue with charging.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to check the docs, but that sounds like a "Neutral-Ground Ground Fault", which is a type of thing GFCIs (RCDs) detect, and that is one thing that EVs and EVSE's look for.

A ground fault is leakage between where power belongs (the hot-neutral loop) and where it does not belong (ground, or shocking a human).

The EVSE is the equipment that connects the EV to the wall. It [contains a smart GFCI and a signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/615551/95888) indicating safe amps right now.  The actual charger, the thing that turns AC power into DC for the battery, is onboard the car.   What makes it a "smart GFCI" is a) it can self-reset, as many ground faults are transient events that don't repeat. And b) in some models it can detect DC leakage.  However a neutral-ground fault would be on the AC side.

Normally the EVSE ("charger"/cable) is responsible for GFCI detection and there's no *standard* way for the EVSE to tell the car what exactly it detected.  So if you're seeing this error on the EVSE, that's that; if it's on the car's display the EVSE has an extra trick, or the car is detecting it.  I suspect it's the car. The ability to distinguish a neutral-ground fault from a hot-ground fault is "not standard equipment" on GFCIs or even EVSEs.

By the way, if you're charging on North American 240V, there is no neutral, there are [2 hot wires](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4). But one of them is called "L2/neutral" (for compatibility with the other 4 continents that use 230V) and it probably means that one.

I note that you're asking "What's this odd message in the logs?" and not "why won't my car charge".  So that tells me this event may have been an intermittent or one-off "nuisance trip" and the auto-reset took care of it.

One way of testing that is to plug the car into a GFCI-protected circuit. (the GFCI could be at the receptacle, at a prior receptacle, a switch, deadfront, or at the breaker).  Generally, ground faults will trip all GFCIs which see the ground fault. (because detection is much faster than the physical tripping, which requires a mechanical thing to move).  Plain old house GFCIs are not smart, and will not self-reset. So you'll notice the trip!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've added an edit with photos and additional details, not sure if they might narrow things down further.